# Unable to use Exchange online in Chrome to apply changes. keeps showing critical error

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, google-chrome, exchangeonline

I've searched for similar problems and still can't find one solution.

This issue started yesterday, then I got an update this morning from chrome. I was thinking the update would solve the problem but apparently it still persists. Every time I try to apply a rule, change group memberships, or other exchange related stuff, I keep getting the following error below. (Pics inserted)[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyTmf.png)

But I find that everything works perfectly on Edge browser. I would like to know if there's a workaround for this as al my bookmarks are already on chrome.

I wil attach below details of the "show report"

### Client Information

User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36
CPU Class: undefined
Platform: Win32
System Language: undefined
User Language: en-US

### CookieEnabled: true

### Exception Details

Date: Tue Oct 29 2019 19:32:12 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)
Message: Script error.
Url: 
Line: 0

### Call Stack

Error
    at Function.ErrorHandling.$Ee (https://r1.res.office365.com/ecp/15.20.2387.25/scripts/common.js:1:190025)
    at ErrorHandling.showUnhandledException (https://r1.res.office365.com/ecp/15.20.2387.25/scripts/common.js:1:189110)

### Dump Event

```
isTrusted = true
message = Script error.
filename = 
lineno = 0
colno = 0
error = null
NONE = 0
CAPTURING_PHASE = 1
AT_TARGET = 2
BUBBLING_PHASE = 3
type = error
target = [object Window]
currentTarget = [object Window]
eventPhase = 2
bubbles = false
cancelable = true
defaultPrevented = false
composed = false
timeStamp = 11911.524999886751
srcElement = [object Window]
returnValue = true
cancelBubble = false
path = [object Window]
composedPath = function composedPath() { [native code] }
stopPropagation = function stopPropagation() { [native code] }
stopImmediatePropagation = function stopImmediatePropagation() { [native code] }
preventDefault = function preventDefault() { [native code] }
initEvent = function initEvent() { [native code] }
```

### Detailed Call Stack

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have toy tried in Incognito Mode in Chrome? Have you tried a different browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in incognito mode, issue happens? How about owa? Is there any error in application log?
According to your description and error message, it seems like a browser frame issue.

In a similar case, some people talk about this issue and you can refer to it.[critical error. The web page isn't loading correctly. Please reload the page by refreshing your browser. Technical Information: Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://webmail.domain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9a0a2904-fedc-4940-99c0-bb52c265f09e/critical-error-the-web-page-isnt-loading-correctly-please-reload-the-page-by-refreshing-your?forum=exchangesvrdeploy)